# Log4j Log hibernate specific messages to separate file

Tags: java, log4j

I want my Hibernate specific logs to go to a separate file using log4j.
I tried this:

```
# Root logger option--First parameter is logLevel, second says redirect to file , third says redirect to standard output alos
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout


# Log everything. Good for troubleshooting
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO,hblog

# Log all JDBC parameters
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=ALL

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender 
log4j.appender.file.File=D:\\a2bnextLogs\\a2bnext.log
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Direct hibernate messages to a log file
log4j.appender.hblog=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender 
log4j.appender.hblog.File=D:\\a2bnextLogs\\hibernate.log
log4j.appender.hblog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.hblog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

But this doesent seem to work.Could anyone suggest what changes I need to make in above configuration?